# Trying to addGuest to Array (print them) in Java - Returns NULL

Tags: java

When I try and print some Java code, it returns null. I know I have something I am missing in my code but I am not sure what. Mind you I am relatively new to Java. I am almost positive it is something in the addGuest method.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class PartyParticipants {
int sizeOfList = 3;     
static String[] guestList;      
String hostName;        
String addGuest;
static int Guest;       

Scanner stdIn = new Scanner(System.in);

public PartyParticipants(int size, String host) {

sizeOfList = size;
hostName = host;
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{

    PartyParticipants party = new PartyParticipants(3, "David Beckham");
    party.addGuest("Roberto Baggio");
    party.addGuest("Zinedine Zidane");
    party.addGuest("Roberto Baggio");
    party.addGuest("Johan Cruyff");
    party.addGuest("Diego Maradona");
    party.printParty();

}


private void addGuest(String string) {


for (int i=0; i<sizeOfList; i++)
{

    Guest++;
    }

if (sizeOfList > 3)

{
    System.out.println(Guest + " cannot come to the party. The guest list is    full.");
}

}



public void printParty()

{
{


    System.out.println("Guest list for " + hostName + "'s party:");

    System.out.println(guestList);


}
}
}
```

Comment: Take a close hard look at your `addGuest` method, where does it actually add the `String` value to the `guestList`?  In fact, where do you actually initialise `guestList`?

Comment: Hmm. Does it seem like I don't initialize it at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi you need to actuaaly initialize your array.. 
like do somthing here

```
static String[] guestList = new String[sizeOfList ]; 
static int Guest = 0;
```

And change addGuest method

```
 private void addGuest(String string) 
 {

        if (Guest <= 3)
        {
            System.out.println(Guest + " cannot come to the party. The guest list is    full.");
        }
        else
        {
            guestList[Guest]=string; 
            Guest++;
         }
  }
```

And a small change in your printParty method..

```
public void printParty()    
{
    System.out.println("Guest list for " + hostName + "'s party:");
for(int i=0;i<guestList.length;i++)
    System.out.println(guestList[i]);
}
```

read more about java..

Comment: Almost there. Instead of returning null it acutally returns something. It returns: Ljava.lang.String;@53c36f46

Comment: @AlecAugustine ok I edited the answer and I suggested the in  changed print party method too.. Hope it works.. If its helpful dont forgot to accept the answer..

Comment: Fixed everything I could but it only returned one person with the rest of the lines null (also removed guest++ since it was creating errors) : Guest list for David Beckham's party:
Diego Maradona
null
null

Comment: @AlecAugustine Paste your changed program .. with this changes its not possible.. you possibly changed something else..

Comment: Yeah I did I see what I did wrong now. Ok I got it!! Thanks for your help man!